# Tricerat Screwdrivers alternative

Tags: windows-server-2008, citrix, drivers, printer

Is there another solution I could use instead of

http://www.tricerat.com/products/screwdrivers

I have used them but the maintenance expired and now we have to move our servers from 2003 to 2008 and these guys are somewhat lacking in support and the overall buying experience.

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I might suggest using Terminal Services Easy Print.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2007/04/26/introducing-terminal-services-easy-print-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Easy Print is great, IF it works for you.

[This blog post](http://forums.zfirm.com/entry.php?44-Backwards-Compatibility-Religion-Microsoft-Printing-and-You) shows that it does not work for everyone...

Comment: @samsmith: Your reference looks like a very edge case to me.

Comment: It is not edge case if you write software that does raw printing.... like we do....

Answer (score 0):

Cortado makes a comparable product called ThinPrint.

http://www.thinprint.com/